# Errors using free() and realloc()

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, memory-movement

I wrote a little piece of code . I was playing with void * pointers in order to create a swap function for basic data types of C. I wrote two versions of this function , because strings are a bit different from the rest of the basic data types ( but maybe I'm wrong ) .The version of this function for int, float and char it works but a when I try to use the one for strings , Valgrind reports me multiple errors . Here's the main:

```
int main(){

 int dimA=0,dimB=0;
 char *v,*g,*str1="heygv",*str2="bag";

 v=malloc(strlen(str1)+1);
 strcpy(v,str1);
 g=malloc(strlen(str2)+1);
 strcpy(g,str2);

 dimA=strlen(v);
 dimB=strlen(g);

 printf("\nX : %s %p ,Y : %s %p \n",v,v,g,g);
 swapStr(v,g,dimA+1,dimB+1);
 printf("\nX : %s %p ,Y : %s %p \n",v,v,g,g);

 free(v);
 free(g);

return 191;

}
```

Here's swap function,it works and swap correctly values of strings :

```
void* swapStr(void* a,void* b,int dimA,int dimB){

void* temp=malloc(dimA);
void* ptr;

    memcpy(temp,a,dimA);

    if(dimB>dimA){

        ptr=realloc(a,dimB);

        if(ptr==NULL){
            printf("\nError 1 realloc in swapStr\n");
            return;
        }else a=ptr;

    }

    memcpy(a,b,dimB);

    if(dimA>dimB){

        ptr=realloc(b,dimA);

        if(ptr==NULL){
            printf("\nError 2 realloc in swapStr\n");
            return;
        }else b=ptr;

    }

    memcpy(b,temp,dimA);

free(temp);
temp=NULL;
}
```

And here ther's Valgrind's report:

```
X : heygv 0x51f2040 ,Y : bag 0x51f2090 
--5756-- REDIR: 0x4ec9080 (libc.so.6:memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x4a2472e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5756-- REDIR: 0x4ed1430 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c2e0d0 (memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14)
--5756-- REDIR: 0x4eb9ab0 (libc.so.6:realloc) redirected to 0x4c2ba52 (realloc)
--5756-- REDIR: 0x4eb8bb0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2ac62 (free)

==5756== Invalid read of size 1
==5756==    at 0x4E7EC15: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== Invalid read of size 1
==5756==    at 0x4EAEBC1: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2092 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== Invalid read of size 1
==5756==    at 0x4EAEBD4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2091 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== Invalid read of size 1
==5756==    at 0x4EC406B: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4EAEB0F: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== Invalid read of size 2
==5756==    at 0x4EC407B: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4EAEB0F: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2091 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
X : bag 0x51f2040 ,Y : bag 0x51f2090 
==5756== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5756==    at 0x4C2ACE9: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x40089D: main (swapVoid.c:49)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== 
==5756== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5756==     in use at exit: 6 bytes in 1 blocks
==5756==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 22 bytes allocated
==5756== 
==5756== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==5756== Checked 65,256 bytes
==5756== 
==5756== 6 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5756==    definitely lost: 6 bytes in 1 blocks
==5756==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5756==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5756==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5756==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5756== 
==5756== ERROR SUMMARY: 11 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5756== 
==5756== 1 errors in context 1 of 7:
==5756== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5756==    at 0x4C2ACE9: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x40089D: main (swapVoid.c:49)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== 
==5756== 1 errors in context 2 of 7:
==5756== Invalid read of size 2
==5756==    at 0x4EC407B: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4EAEB0F: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2091 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== 
==5756== 1 errors in context 3 of 7:
==5756== Invalid read of size 1
==5756==    at 0x4EC406B: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4EAEB0F: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== 
==5756== 1 errors in context 4 of 7:
==5756== Invalid read of size 1
==5756==    at 0x4EAEBC1: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2092 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== 
==5756== 2 errors in context 5 of 7:
==5756== Invalid read of size 1
==5756==    at 0x4EAEBD4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2091 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== 
==5756== 4 errors in context 6 of 7:
==5756== Invalid read of size 1
==5756==    at 0x4E7EC15: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==5756==    by 0x400885: main (swapVoid.c:46)
==5756==  Address 0x51f2090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5756==    at 0x4C2BB1C: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5756==    by 0x400959: swapStr (swapVoid.c:77)
==5756==    by 0x400860: main (swapVoid.c:45)
==5756== 
==5756== ERROR SUMMARY: 11 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The errors seem to be linked to the wrong usage of free ()(or realloc ?) ,but why?Another strange fact Is that, If I run this program without valgrind ,it works , instead now you see that strings are not Correctly swapped.

Every possible suggestion is well accepted about  how create a swap function that can swap ,at least ,basic data types.

Comment: `a=ptr;` and `b=ptr;` are not update original pointer. because `a` and `b` are local variable(just copy of pointer).

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass a pointer to your `char*` into `swapStr()` because if the pointer is reallocated, you need the string pointer (`char*`) to point to the newly-allocated memory.

eg.

```
void* swapStr(char **ap,char** bp,int dimA,int dimB){
    char *a = *ap;
    char *b = *bp;
    // ... rest of the function, including realloc
    *ap = a;
    *bp = b;
 }

swapStr(&a, &b, dimA, dimB);
```

This ensures that if your `a` or `b` pointer was reallocated, the caller's pointer is also updated.

---

Prefer using correctly-typed pointers (`char*`) rather than `void*` when they are pointing to arrays of `char`.

Answer (score 2):

First the `void*` function isn't returning a pointer (something the compiler should have warned you).

The `main()` function does not know the pointers that were reallocated in `swapStr()`

```
swapStr(v,g,dimA+1,dimB+1);
printf("\nX : %s %p ,Y : %s %p \n",v,v,g,g);
```

Try with a double * pointers in the function

```
void swapStr(void **a, void **b, int dimA, int dimB)
...
swapStr(&v,&g,dimA+1,dimB+1);
```

so that the function can write the reallocated pointer values to the vars in `main()`.

Lastly not all return paths `free(temp)`. Here is a rehash of your code. I left left the function types as `void**` because you want it to swap other data types too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fatal(char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
}

void swapStr(void **a, void **b, int dimA, int dimB){
    void *temp = malloc(dimA);
    if (temp == NULL)
        fatal("Error allocating memory for temp\n");
    memcpy(temp, *a, dimA);

    if(dimB>dimA){
        *a = realloc(*a, dimB);
        if (*a == NULL)
            fatal("Error reallocating memory for a\n");
    }
    if(dimA>dimB){
        *b = realloc(*b, dimA);
        if (*b == NULL)
            fatal("Error reallocating memory for b\n");
    }

    memcpy(*a, *b, dimB);
    memcpy(*b, temp, dimA);
    free(temp);
}

int main(void){
    int dimA=0, dimB=0;
    char *str1="heygv", *str2="bag";
    void *v, *g;

    v = malloc(strlen(str1)+1);
    if (v == NULL)
        fatal("Error allocating memory for v\n");
    strcpy(v, str1);
    g = malloc(strlen(str2)+1);
    if (g == NULL)
        fatal("Error allocating memory for g\n");
    strcpy(g, str2);

    dimA = strlen(v);
    dimB = strlen(g);
    printf("\nX : %s %p ,Y : %s %p \n", (char*)v, v, (char*)g, g);

    swapStr(&v, &g, dimA+1, dimB+1);
    printf("\nX : %s %p ,Y : %s %p \n", (char*)v, v, (char*)g, g);

    free(v);
    free(g);

    return 0;
}
```